# UICollectionViewCell - animate cell height change when its content changes

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a really simple `UICollectionView`, using iOS 13's `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`. The cells have a vertical `UIStackView`, and when you press the "toggle details" button, I simple change the `isHidden` value of the `detailsView`. When the cells then inform the view controller that it needs to execute `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`, everything basically works: the details view is toggled on and off. But it doesn't animate this, so it looks a bit jarring.

[image]
[image]

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet private var collectionView: UICollectionView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = createLayout()
  }

  private func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(200))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(200))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])

    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.contentInsets = .init(top: 16, leading: 16, bottom: 16, trailing: 16)
    section.interGroupSpacing = 16

    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
    return layout
  }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.resize = { [weak self] in
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
        self?.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
      }
    }
    return cell
  }
}

class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
  @IBOutlet private var detailsView: UIView!

  var resize: (() -> Void)?

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
  }

  @IBAction private func toggleDetails() {
    detailsView.isHidden.toggle()
    resize?()
  }
}
```

Repro project: https://github.com/kevinrenskers/CellHeight.

How can I animate the toggling of this details view, so that the height change animates? And can that be used in combination with the `UIStackView` and showing/hiding its children views? Please note that the details view doesn't have a fixed height in the real world app, so I can't just switch the cell height between two fixed values.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a collection view instead of a table view?

Comment: Yes. In the real app I also have horizontally scrolling sections in the collectionview, which is what UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout is perfect for.

Comment: Hmm... I have done very little with collection views, in part because (my impression is) it's notoriously difficult to manage cell sizing / resizing. You might want to take a look at this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/7246-expanding-cells-in-ios-collection-views -- not quite the same, but might give you a direction for your implementation. Unless your experience is different, my approach - since tableview cell expand / collapse is so easy - would be to use a tableview, with "horizontal scrolling" collection view(s) embedded in the tableview cells as needed (a comment, not a solution).

Comment: what if you'll animate the height of the cell (change the from the current to the new one, or even use `CGAffineTransform`) and then in animation completion call `invalidateLayout`, so collectionView has to recalculate the size of the items

Comment: I haven't been able to get that to work, no. Just try it in the example project and submit it as an answer if you get it to work :)

Comment: @KevinRenskers did you ever get a solution to this? I'm wanting to do something similar but I'm hitting the same problems. It looks like I will have to insert new cells ro get the expansion rather than having one cell that changes height.

Comment: @bencallis did you find any solution to that problem?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are supposed to call `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` outside of the animation block, and then call `self?.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()` in the animation block.

Comment: I actually had a call with an Apple engineer during last WWDC about this problem, and there's basically no solution.

Answer (score 0):

With the collection view animated, I folk your repo and make some changes.

https://github.com/lebaotrung93/CellHeight

It works. But with UIStackView, It seems hard to manage the size of it in `CollectionView` due to its own behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the code! However the animation looks really bad, and you disabled the UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout code. It still mostly works with it enabled again, but the animation is still pretty bad :/ I'll try it without the stackview.

Comment: Yes, remove the stackview make the animated better a lot. It automatically resize so I think when reload, event just a single row, the others still call reload !!?.